# How to build a Dockerfile which runs a Shiny app using JDBC/Hive (needs rJava)?

Tags: r, docker, hive, shiny, rjdbc

I need a Dockerfile to run a **Shiny app capable to connect to Hive** using JDBC. The package RJDBC depends on the package rJava, hence Java. Now, I tested multiple options:

- Taking **rocker/verse** which has Java, and **add Shiny** manually.
- Taking **rocker/shiny**, and **add Java** manually.

Both options were partially working, but not fully. The R code for the Hive connection is the following:

```
require(RJDBC)
urlJDBC = "jdbc:hive2://...:8443/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=./cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit?hive.server2.transport.mode=http;hive.server2.thrift.http.path=gateway/default/hive"
driver = JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "hive-jdbc-standalone.jar", identifier.quote="`")
con = dbConnect(driver, urlJDBC, "username", "password")
```

I also added within the Dockerfile the JDBC Jar file with the line:

```
ADD ... ./hive-jdbc-standalone.jar
```

However, I had no success to make it run.
Does somebody have a blueproint DOCKERFILE which works with Shiny and Hive/JDBC? Would be great

M

Answer (score 2):

Solved after having been on the wrong direction for hours.

The problem was in rights management. **Read access to the JAR file was missing**.

The new DOCKERFILE is quite simple:

```
FROM rocker/shiny

# Download and rename JAR file with JDBC HIVE driver.
WORKDIR /srv/shiny-server/apps/shinyhive
ADD <..jar-on-local-server..> ./hive-jdbc-standalone.jar

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk liblzma-dev libbz2-dev libicu-dev libssl-dev \
    && R CMD javareconf

RUN R -e "install.packages('RJDBC', repos='http://cran.r-project.org')"

RUN chmod 777 -R .
COPY . .
COPY ./shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```